# Android : Store text in string

Tags: android

I have an activity in which a toast returns the other part of sentence if we put the first part of sentence correctly. I want to get the other part (twinkle twinkle) from the Android resources, but I don't know how.

```
 final EditText     hetext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text1);        
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
        {

        final String edittext= hetext.getText().toString();
                    if(edittext.trim().equals("twinkle twinkle"))
                    {


 // toast ( little star )

                }  

                else
                {


//toast ( the word is not matching) 

                }
```

Comment: As I told you should use the debugger and set a breakpoint. Look at this tutorial to learn how to debug your code: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We misunderstood your question. The awser you are looking for is:

`String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.some_string);`

getResources() is a method of the Context class. If you are inside a Activity or a Service (which extend Context) you can use it like in this snippet.

**Also note that the whole language dependency can be taken care of by the android framework.** 
Simply create different folders for each language. If english is your default language, just put the english strings into res/values/strings.xml. Then create a new folder values-ru and put the russian strings with identical names into res/values-ru/strings.xml. From this point on android selects the correct one depending on the device locale for you, either when you call getString() or when referencing strings in XML via @string/mystring. The ones from res/values/strings.xml are the fallback ones, if you don't have a folder covering the users locale, this one will be used as default values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead to load string from resources,

```
String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you condition to sth weaker `if(edittext.trim().contains("twinkle twinkle"))`
or make sure that you string is't capitalized or sth, and try to use debugger.

Comment: I need it like `(R.string.some_text) ` I'm new to it. I don't know how to use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
final String edittext= hetext.getText().toString();
//consider.for example you put below string in a edittext.      
String se="sethu is a good boy";

if(se.trim().contains("is"))
{
 se+="twinkle";
 System.out.print(se);
}
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You all misunderstood my question, my code is working the way i want. But, what i need is to store text (twinkle twinkle) in res/values/strings.xml, so that i can use `(R.string.other_part) ` instead of twinkle twinkle.